# On IE 11 enter key on anchor tag not triggering click function

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, coffeescript

This is my anchor tag in my html

```
<a class="c-alert__icon--title-icon c-alert__icon--info js-toggle-help fa-question-circle far" aria-label="expand" href="#"></a>
```

In my app.js.coffee

```
$(".js-toggle-help").click ->
  if $(this).is( ".is-active" )
     $(this).attr('aria-label','collapse');
  else
     $(this).attr('aria-label','expand');
     $('.js-help-tip').focus();
```

On mouse click is working fine but on enter keystroke is not working. 
This is happening only on IE 11.

Comment: possibly try `.on('click keyup', func`....

Comment: is anchor tag have id?

Comment: @NegiRox it does not have any id

Comment: on win10 and ie11 it works

Comment: you are binding click function..